# Android viewport size

Tags: android

I'm new to developing Android APPs.

I managed to compile my first OpenGL Application, but encountered a little problem.

First, my current code can be found here: https://gist.github.com/1281394

When I start the application, the viewport has the size of this green rectangle as seen in the following screenshot:

[image: http://s3.postimage.org/ugi2tflob/android.jpg]

I need a way to specify the size of the drawable space, since I want to draw elements on the entire screen.

I'd appreciate every hint :)

Many thanks in advance,
Jakob

Comment: I loaded lesson2 of the tutorial (changed the color value of glClearColor to red) and executed it on my virtual device (screen resolution 1280x800 - same as the targeted tablet).


I still got the same error (http://postimage.org/image/2dfxwtoys/).


Tried to google a lot, but I dont really know, how to ask the correct questions about this concer, since I'm totally new to OpenGL/Android SDK.


Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [these [NeHe] tutorials.](http://insanitydesign.com/wp/projects/nehe-android-ports/) They are a fantastic reference for starting OpenGL